# how should i do this dragging and dropping framework file to the framework folder inside the xcode project using command line arguments.(Terminal)

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am working an build automating project. Im using grunt . There was xcode project , in order to build the project i have to add a external framework file to the framework folder at the xcode project.(Drag and drop).

So when im doing the build using grunt command, how should i do this dragging and dropping framework file to the framework folder inside the xcode project using command line arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Open Your Project select the target**

[image]

**Press the "+" sign to add a new Framework.**

[image]

**Press "Add Other" Button**

[image]

**Select your .framework file & press open button.**

[image]

Comment: How to do the same thins using terminal window.(Command line arguments)

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea about it.

Comment: Thanks any way for making so clean n clear screen shots and explain it